# CDK Deploy fails with Access Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk

i am trying to deploy a aws cfn stack using CDK, but am getting an access denied. The stack contains a few lambda apps with [`code.fromAsset()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.Code.html#static-fromwbrassetpath-options), it seems the error is caused by the asset publishing.

The bucket is KMS encrypted, the bootstrap was done as per below:

```sh
cdk bootstrap <acc_id>/<region> \
   --public-access-block-configuration false \
   --bootstrap-kms-key-id <key_arn> \
   --app "python app.py"
```

Bootstrap is done successfully, but the deploy is failing due to the error shown above.

thank you very much for your attention,

```
[0%] start: Publishing 87acds2ad323asd23e6e42374b49601d6c6858c4ad21asfasd213eddd18f6bd:current
[100%] fail: Access Denied

 ❌  stack failed: Error: Failed to publish one or more assets. See the error messages above for more information.
    at Object.publishAssets (...\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\util\asset-publishing.ts:25:11)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at Object.deployStack (...\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\api\deploy-stack.ts:223:3)
    at CdkToolkit.deploy (...\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\lib\cdk-toolkit.ts:181:24)
    at main (...\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\bin\cdk.ts:268:16)
    at initCommandLine (...\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\aws-cdk\bin\cdk.ts:188:9)
Failed to publish one or more assets. See the error messages above for more information.
```

Comment: are you sure your user has the required permissions? In this case probably uploading to s3

Comment: Hi @JonnyRimek, yes it does have all needed permissions

Comment: This hit me after running `cdk bootstrap` with CDK 2. It silently renamend the S3 bucket so the bucket name pattern in the policy no longer matched.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the exactly same problem. I had some SCPs in place and deactivating those temporarily solved the problem.

In the end, I had a permission for KMS missing in my SCPs. Adding the following statement to the permissions solved my problem:

```
{
  "Sid": "AllowKMS",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": [
    "kms:*"
  ],
  "Resource": [
    "*"
  ]
}
```